# Configuring Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Fresh windows installation, want to try the new Visual Studio. But exactly, which workloads do I need to install? I am a student of Computer Science and I only program a Console Application in either C or C++

I don't want to checklist all the workloads since it's so huge. I installed with no workloads and I can't get this to work. I used to work with Visual C++ 2010 Express and there is a "Win32 Console Application"

Comment: Well just check the C/C++ one then..

Comment: @Milney which one exactly? There is so many workloads that do contain C/C++ moreover each of them cost me like 3-6GB

Comment: No - there is exactly one... and it is the only one with C++ in the name?